# value of a variable can't be stored

Tags: c++

the compiler says this code has no error but when i enter students total, the value of jlh it isn't stored and it won't loop jlh times. how should i change the code?

```
using std::string;

int main(){
 int jlh,x,y;
 string abs;

 char **mhs=new char*[100];
    
     cout<<"enter students total: ";
     cin>>jlh;
       
     for(x=0;x<jlh;x++){     
     cout<<"enter students name: ";
        cin>>mhs[x];
        cout<<"enter students presensi: ";
        cin>>abs[x];
        cout<<endl;
      }
      
 
  getch();
  }
```

Comment: You never allocate `mhs[x]`.  You should change it by using a `std::vector` instead of a C style array, and by using `std::string` instead of C style strings.

Comment: Also, memory for `abs` is not being allocated before `abs[x]` is used, either

Comment: ohh thats whyy.. but @Eljay can u explain more pls? i still don't understand. i put std::string at the begining i'm sorry i forgot to put it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must allocate place to store what are read before reading things:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    int jlh,x,y;
    string abs;

    char **mhs=new char*[100];

    cout<<"enter students total: ";
    cin>>jlh;

    abs.resize(jlh); // allocate for presensi
    for(x=0;x<jlh;x++){
        cout<<"enter students name: ";
        mhs[x] = new char[1024000]; // allocate for name, hoping this is enough...
        cin>>mhs[x];
        cout<<"enter students presensi: ";
        cin>>abs[x];
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of raw arrays should be better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
    int jlh,x,y;

    cout<<"enter students total: ";
    cin>>jlh;

    // allocate jlh elements for each vectors
    std::vector<string> mhs(jlh);
    std::vector<char> abs(jlh);

    for(x=0;x<jlh;x++){
        cout<<"enter students name: ";
        cin>>mhs[x];
        cout<<"enter students presensi: ";
        cin>>abs[x];
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have another question. how's it going to be if abs var and mhs has the same data type which is char? i tried to change into std::vector<char>mhs(jlh); and when i run it, it won't loop perfectly like the first time

Comment: @pluto98 It will depend on what you want to do, but at least you should declare another variable of type `string` to read the name input if the input format isn't changed.